# Multi Site WordPress rewrite rules in Nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I'm trying to run a multi domain blog installation with WordPress and Nginx. The last step is to configure some rewrite rules in `.htaccess` (apache only) for the webserver. How do I translate this into Nginx rewrite rules?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[nginx rewrite rules example for Wordpress 3](http://blog.delacelle.com/post/2010/06/23/nginx-rewrites-rules-for-wordpress-3-multi-blog-php-fpm/) :

```
server{
    server_name *.example.com;  
    listen 80;
    #on server block
    ##necessary if using a multi-site plugin
    server_name_in_redirect off;
    ##necessary if running Nginx behind a reverse-proxy
    port_in_redirect off;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/example-com-access.log;

    location / {
        root   /var/www/example.com/wordpress;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        rewrite ^.*/files/(.*)$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^.+/?(/wp-.*) $1 last;
            rewrite ^.+/?(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
            rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php?q=$1 last;
        }
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$
    {
        root /var/www/example.com/wordpress;
        rewrite ^/.*(/wp-.*/.*\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ $1 last;
        rewrite ^.*/files/(.*(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }

    location ~ wp\-.*\.php|wp\-admin|\.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/example.com/wordpress$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Above is missing a space after the rewrite ^.*/files/(.*(html|jpg|....... you need a space after the $ and before /wp-includes/ms-files.php. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This nginx rewrite rules for WordPress have solved my problem perfectly,including changing ex.com/wp-admin to ex.com/wp-admin/.

But i've found a bug inside which wasted me several hours as follows：
If the static url include `.html` just like `/%category%/%post_id%.html`,you have to insted of:

```html
location ~* ^.+\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$
    {
        root /var/www/example.com/wordpress;
        rewrite ^/.*(/wp-.*/.*\.(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ $1 last;
        rewrite ^.*/files/(.*(html|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }
```

Change it to:

```html
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js)$
    {
        root /var/www/example.com/wordpress;
        rewrite ^/.*(/wp-.*/.*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ $1 last;
        rewrite ^.*/files/(.*(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js))$ /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$1 last;
        expires 30d;
        break;
    }
```

Or,u'll had '404 page not found' error in the content pages!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
location ~ wp\-.*\.php|wp\-admin|\.php$ {
```

Change it to:

```
location ~ .php$
```

Allows it to direct

```
blog.com/wp-admin
```

to

```
blog.com/wp-admin/
```